Hide and Seek game with Unity ML agent. Advice on reward system for going towards hider
I am looking for some insights on my rewards for seeker agent. I want him to be able to find hider in maze-like environment. I am using Raycasts (Ray Perception Sensor) as observation of environment. Here is the code, let me know if you need anything else. All help will be appreciated.
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;
using UnityEngine;

public class SeekerAgent : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private RayPerceptionSensorComponent3D rayPerceptionSensor;
    [SerializeField] private HiderAgent hiderAgent;
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer groundMesh;
    [SerializeField] private Material winMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private Material defaultMaterial;

    private int episodeCounter = 0;
    private Rigidbody seekerRb;
    private Vector3 positionOfHider;
    private bool hiderFound;
    private float previousDistanceToHider = float.MaxValue;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        seekerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        episodeCounter++;
        hiderFound = false;
        positionOfHider = Vector3.zero;
        seekerRb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        seekerRb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-6, 4), 0.25f, 3.38f);
    }

    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        AddReward(-1f / MaxStep);
        MoveAgent(actions.DiscreteActions);

        if (hiderFound)
        {
            float currentDistanceToHider = Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, positionOfHider);

            if (currentDistanceToHider < previousDistanceToHider)
                AddReward(1 / currentDistanceToHider);
            else
                AddReward(-1 / currentDistanceToHider);

            previousDistanceToHider = currentDistanceToHider;
        }
    }

    private void MoveAgent(ActionSegment<int> actions)
    {
        var moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        var rotateDirection = Vector3.zero;

        var actionsMoving = actions[0];
        var actionsRotating = actions[1];
        switch (actionsMoving)
        {
            case 1:
                moveDirection = movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.forward;
                break;
            case 2:
                moveDirection = movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.back;
                break;
        }

        if (actionsRotating == 1)
        {
            rotateDirection = Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (actionsRotating == 2)
        {
            rotateDirection = Vector3.up * -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }


        transform.Rotate(rotateDirection);
        transform.Translate(moveDirection, Space.Self);
    }

    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        var discreteActionsOut = actionsOut.DiscreteActions;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            discreteActionsOut[1] = 1;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            discreteActionsOut[1] = 2;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            discreteActionsOut[0] = 1;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            discreteActionsOut[0] = 2;
    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.localRotation);

        if (!hiderFound)
            foreach (var raySensor in rayPerceptionSensor.RaySensor.RayPerceptionOutput.RayOutputs)
            {
                if (raySensor.HitGameObject != null && raySensor.HitGameObject.CompareTag("Hider"))
                {
                    AddReward(0.1f);
                    positionOfHider = raySensor.HitGameObject.transform.localPosition;
                    hiderFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if (hiderFound)
            sensor.AddObservation(positionOfHider);
        else
            sensor.AddObservation(Vector3.zero);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            AddReward(-0.5f);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Hider"))
        {
            AddReward(3f);
            if (episodeCounter % 2 == 0)
                groundMesh.material = winMaterial;
            else
                groundMesh.material = defaultMaterial;
            hiderAgent.EndEpisode();
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}


Currently, seeker is rewarded if he “sees” with one of rays a hider, and gets constant reward for going towards him, and negative reward for going away from him. Also he gets a reward when he touch hider, and negative reward when he collides with wall.
As it is, i am not satisfied with how the seeker is working, as now it seems that he prioritize going in circles around a map, and not prioritizing the behavior in which he goes towards a hider as soon as he sees him, which is how he should act.

It's probably a matter of balancing the rewards .. in my (very little) experience with MLAgents the best results are usually the ones where the reward system is extremely simple .. whenever you want to enforce a certain behavior too much by using too complex rewards it starts to "misbehave" unless you really find a good balance. For instance you could try and rather just reward a successful catch .. it will take more time in the beginning for the agents to understand what they get rewards for but then it is simple enough for them to focus on that only

e.g. Unity has a beginner tutorial for an agent push a box, jump over a wall and reach a target. You would think they give some rewards for pushing the box .. or climbing on it .. or jump over the wall .. results that the only reward ever given is for reaching the target and a punishment for time passed .. that's what I mean by use over simplified rewards and let the agent figure out the rest itself

Thank you on your response. I will try it, as i saw it in their tutorials, but i thought this way i will get results faster. It seems i need to let them "learn" for couple of hours.
Although, i would still like to find some kind of rewarding system that is balanced. Let me know if you have some suggestion, I'm open to try it.
